# Selecting by subset of multiindex level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

**Toy example**

Suppose I have the dataframe `df` shown below

```
           C
L0 L1 L2    
0  w  P   11
      Q    9
      R   21
      S    4
   x  P    3
      Q    0
      R   23
      S   20
   y  P   19
      Q    0
      R    7
      S   13
   z  P   17
      Q    0
      R    5
      S    1
1  w  P    8
      Q    2
      R   12
      S    0
   x  P   22
      Q   14
      R    2
      S   18
   y  P    6
      Q    0
      R   16
      S   15
   z  P   10
      Q    0
      R    8
      S    0
```

Note that the rows of `df` are indexed by 3-level multi-index.

I can find the minimum of the `C` column for each value of the `L2` level, as follows:

```
In [58]: df.groupby(level='L2').min()
Out[58]: 
    C
L2   
P   3
Q   0
R   2
S   0
```

Similarly, the following expression shows the values of `L2` for which this minimum is greater than 0:

```
In [59]: df.groupby(level='L2').min() > 0
Out[59]: 
        C
L2       
P    True
Q   False
R    True
S   False
```

**Question:** How can I select the rows of the original dataframe `df` corresponding to the values of `L2` for which the minimum of `C` is greater than 0?

---

In this simple example the problem boils down to selecting the rows of `df` whose `L2` value is either `'P'` or `'R'`.  Therefore, it would not be difficult to brute-force the problem by concatenating the rows for `L2='P'` with those for `L2='R'`.

In the application I have in mind, however, such a solution becomes unwieldy, since here the `L2` level has ~2000 values, and for about half of them, the minimum is greater than 0.

Therefore, I'm looking for a more scalable way to solve this selection problem.

**DATA**

```
L0  L1  L2  C
0   w   P   11
0   w   Q   9
0   w   R   21
0   w   S   4
0   x   P   3
0   x   Q   0
0   x   R   23
0   x   S   20
0   y   P   19
0   y   Q   0
0   y   R   7
0   y   S   13
0   z   P   17
0   z   Q   0
0   z   R   5
0   z   S   1
1   w   P   8
1   w   Q   2
1   w   R   12
1   w   S   0
1   x   P   22
1   x   Q   14
1   x   R   2
1   x   S   18
1   y   P   6
1   y   Q   0
1   y   R   16
1   y   S   15
1   z   P   10
1   z   Q   0
1   z   R   8
1   z   S   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's one way**

Store the `L2` values needed

```
In [413]: m = df.groupby(level='L2').min() > 0

In [414]: m
Out[414]:
        C
L2
P    True
Q   False
R    True
S   False
```

Using, `get_level_values(index_level_name).isin(to_be_filtered)` filter only needed values.

```
In [415]: df[df.index.get_level_values('L2').isin(m.loc[m.C, :].index)]
Out[415]:
           C
L0 L1 L2
0  w  P   11
      R   21
   x  P    3
      R   23
   y  P   19
      R    7
   z  P   17
      R    5
1  w  P    8
      R   12
   x  P   22
      R    2
   y  P    6
      R   16
   z  P   10
      R    8
```

**Here's another way**. Using, transform and subset selection

```
In [430]: df[(df.groupby(level='L2').transform('min') > 0).C]
Out[430]:
           C
L0 L1 L2
0  w  P   11
      R   21
   x  P    3
      R   23
   y  P   19
      R    7
   z  P   17
      R    5
1  w  P    8
      R   12
   x  P   22
      R    2
   y  P    6
      R   16
   z  P   10
      R    8
```

Details

```
In [416]: m.loc[m.C, :].index
Out[416]: Index([u'P', u'R'], dtype='object', name=u'L2')
```

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, `m.loc[m.C, :]` (instead of `m[m]`) obviates the `dropna`.

Comment: And, realized you may not need `m` using `transform` method.